# Aliens want to destroy all dogs because they are seen as next step in evolution beyond Man

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I read a SF short story years ago, I think it may have been in high school back in the 1970s. Aliens come to earth, to kill all the dogs, because they see Man as destroying himself, and dogs as evolving to take Man's place, thus being a threat to the aliens. Humanity agrees to kill all the dogs to get rid of the aliens, but in fact have taken border collies (?) deep underground in order to save them and ensure that they evolve.

Does anyone know the title/author of this short story?

Thank you in advance for your assistance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Except for the publication date, this sounds exactly like *Preemption* by Charlie Rosenkrantz, which was published in [Analog in June 2006](http://www.analogsf.com/0606/issue_06.shtml) and anthologized in David G. Hartwell's [*The Year's Best SF 12*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0061252085) in 2007.

The aliens were contracted to eliminate dogs:

> AT THE REQUEST OF A SPECIES THAT WE HAVE ENTERED INTO A MUTUALLY BENEFICIAL ARRANGEMENT WITH, WE ARE ELIMINATING A THREAT TO THE FUTURE BALANCE OF POWER IN THIS PART OF THE GALAXY.

Several breeds were saved:

> Tails were wagging that belonged to Irish Shepherds, Dalmatians, German Shepherds, and Pomeranians. From Golden Retrievers to English Sheepdogs, Labradors to Papillons, there were thirty-seven breeds represented as well as a broad assortment of mutts.

The reason the dogs were being eliminated was:

> NO OTHER SPECIES ON YOUR PLANET EXHIBITS THE SAME EAGERNESS TO LEARN AS YOUR CANINE SPECIES DOES. [*elided*] IT IS THIS CAPACITY, ALONG WITH ALARMINGLY PROLIFIC BREEDING, THAT WOULD HAVE SWIFTLY PROPELLED THEM TO FULL SENTIENCE AND DOMINATION OF THIS ARM OF THE GALAXY.

Comment: Just got a copy of "Year's Best SF 12", edited by David G. Hartwell and Kathryn Cramer. You are correct.  "Preemption" by Charlie Rosenkrantz it was.

Thanks.

John V. Karavitis