# Short story about aliens trying to eliminate dogs from the Earth

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

The story is about a series of anomalous incidents leading to the death of many people. Turns out, these explosions centered around dogs. Aliens are in orbit, intent on destroying every dog on the planet because their extrapolations show how dogs will be the triumphant race in the universe. The story ends deep underground where the military has a bunch of dogs, and they're training them to get revenge on those aliens. Last scene is from a dog's point-of-view, about wanting to feel grass under his feet, sunshine on his face, and wanting to please humans by chasing a ball.

Comment: Roughly speaking, when did you read this? Was it in a magazine or an anthology of any sort? Do you recall any descriptions or names of characters?

Comment: I seem to remember this very same question. Can't find it here though, maybe it was on another site.

Comment: Check out this question: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/67544/aliens-want-to-destroy-all-dogs-because-they-are-seen-as-next-step-in-evolution

Comment: Yes! Preemption by Charlie Rosenkrantz is the tale which has been haunting me for the past three years! Thank you so much!